# Javascript and jQuery not working when I put it into a seperate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my html file

```
<head>
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/aboutmestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src= "js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src= "js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#menubar").click(function(){
         $("#dropbox").animate({
           top: '150px',
           height:'400px',
         });
       });
     });

    </script>

<body>
    <div id="dropbox">

    </div>
</body>
```

However, when I move my js code into a file called aboutme.js and comment out the js code in the header, it doesnt work.  My aboutme.js file looks like this

```
window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad() {
  $("#dropbox").click(function(){
    $("#dropbox").animate({
      height:'400px',
    });
  });
};
```

However, the code works if i leave it in my html header.  Any reason why?  Thanks!

Comment: Please look in the browser error console as the first place to look to discover your own coding errors.  You really shouldn't have to come here for simple errors that are already explained in the error console.

Comment: Move your custom `<script src= "js/aboutme.js" ...>` **under** libraries it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're including your jQuery code *before* the jQuery library.

```
<script src="js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just like in your original version, you must include your custom jQuery code *AFTER* the jQuery library...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

There's absolutely no reason to remove your DOM ready event handler just because it's in an external file.  The contents of your external file can be exactly the same as you had it within the `<head>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menubar").click(function(){
        $("#dropbox").animate({
            top: '150px',
            height:'400px',
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JS files in the order so that the files that are dependent on other file should be included aftr those other files.

So, if you add aboutme AFTER jquery, it should work

```
<head>
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/aboutmestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
     <script src= "js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // add aboutme here 
    </script>
    <script src= "js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#menubar").click(function(){
         $("#dropbox").animate({
           top: '150px',
           height:'400px',
         });
       });
     });

        </script>
    <body>
        <div id="dropbox">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line of code:

```
<script src= "js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Below this line of code:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

It should look like this:

```
<head>
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/aboutmestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src= "js/aboutme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src= "js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
```